# Would a web site displaying incorrect ratings be considered to be a form of False Advertising

Tags: canada, false-advertising

I'm curious to know if a "gig" website (ie Uber, Airbnb, Rover, Skip, ...) displays the wrong star rating for a profile (intentional or not) could it be considered to be a form of false advertising?

From [GOC: False or Misleading Representations and Deceptive Marketing Practices](https://ised-isde.canada.ca/site/competition-bureau-canada/en/deceptive-marketing-practices/types-deceptive-marketing-practices/false-or-misleading-representations-and-deceptive-marketing-practices): "... All representations, in any form whatever, that are false or misleading in a material respect are subject to the Act. If a representation could influence a consumer to buy or use the product or service advertised, it is material. ..."

I ask because recently I registered as a "gig worker" on one of these sites and when I was looking at my competition I noticed that some profiles were "advertised" as having an average star rating of 5.0 where statistically it was extremely improbable that this was true (Example at end of the post).

As a client of several of these sites, I've noticed that I have a bias towards profiles with 5.0 star ratings, but I also assume that the way sites calculate star ratings is immutable.

[Displayed Star Rating] = Sum([Reviewer Allocated Star Ratiging]) / Count([Reviewer Allocated Star Rating])*

*(Excluding Expunged Reviews)

As a client who only wishes to receive a service from a profile that has maintained a 5.0-star rating, I feel that I'm being incorrectly influenced to request a service from a provider that has not met my minimum requirements.

Also as a competitor to a profile which is potentially erroneously advertised as having 5.0 stars, I'm at an unfair disadvantage since:

I can't take full advantage of the benefits of having 5.0 star rating (less competition/supply for clients who would only take 5.0 star rated profiles);

and if I lose my 5.0 star I have no method to influence the rating system to display my profile as having a 5.0 star rating.

**Edit** To answer a question left in the comments. The reason why I believe that my equation is correct is because of the following facts.

From [Overview of the dashboard](https://support-ca.rover.com/hc/en-ca/articles/16387866497556-What-do-the-insights-on-my-dashboard-mean-#h_01H2GM3EESP84CEM4961H8XH78) they define the Star rating section of the dashboard to be:

> This section shows your **average** star rating for all bookings with
> reviews, along with the total number of reviews you received from your clients.

Accompanied by this description is an image of the UI showing a sample dashboard with a user's "star rating" to be 4.9.

[image: Description Of Star Rating]

This UI is reused when looking at a user's profile which and with the lack of any information on the site expressing a difference between a user's star rating in their public profile vs the star rating found on their dashboard I believe that these two values represent the same.

From the definition, we see that they describe this value as being the "**average** star rating for all bookings".

This is further reinforced when looking at how they describe their [Star Sitter program](https://support-ca.rover.com/hc/en-ca/articles/16397282976020-What-is-the-Star-Sitter-program-#h_01H3ZDXDAF7S9T2WQCY5C3MWZ9).

> ...
>
> To qualify for Star Sitter status, you must have:
>
> Completed 10 or more bookings
>
> A 4.9+ **average** star rating
>
> ...

From [Average Law and Legal Definition](https://definitions.uslegal.com/a/average/) I get the definition to be

> The term average can mean the usual, typical or ordinary level.
> Average can be a value which represents a broad sample of subjects. In
> mathematics, average refers to the median or mean of a series. In
> Maritime Law, average means a part of liability for loss to an insured
> ship during the voyage. There can be two types of average namely,
> general and particular average.

Now the definition in Canada might be different so I'll expand the mathematical definition to also include `mode` so that a numerical star rating average for all bookings could represent the `mean`, `median` or `mode` of the star ratings assigned by all reviewers.

Now for this particular case both the `mode` and `median` can be discounted by showing a sample of average star ratings that are impossible to get if using the `mode` or `median` of the set as the average of that set.

From their own example for `star sitter program` they show the same panel from a search result showing a users star rating to be `4.9`

[image: Example of Star Sitter Program]

From a search I just did

[image: Example of returned results from a search]

Now the Rover doesn't allow a user to submit fractional stars for a review so a `mode` of `4.9` is impossible to get and similarly a `median` of `4.9` would also be impossible to get. Leaving only the `mean` as the only possible average that they are using.

Hence the calculation for mean is `avg = sum(x)/count(x) for x in X where X is the set of all reviews for a profile`

**Example that I think shows False Advertising**

[Profile in question](https://www.rover.com/members/vita-v-every-dog-must-have-his-day/?utm_source=sitter_profile_share&utm_medium=android&utm_campaign=490382900&utm_nooverride=1&_branch_match_id=1233051753566238625&_branch_referrer=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8soKSkottLXL9Iryi9LLdJLzs%2FVdywsMC0PAQAczIRjGgAAAA%3D%3D) *Note that when I started doing my research (a week or so ago), at that time this profile only had 55 reviews while today it now has 57 reviews.

For this example, I am assuming that if a written reviewer comment is still visible on a profile then that reviewer's rating of the service offered by the profile is still included in the calculation for the profile's star rating (ie the reviewer's review and rating have not been expunged).

A profile has a 5.0-star rating with 55 reviews.

Doing some simple math it can be seen that for this to be true the worse possible scores the profile could have gotten would be (2x 4-Star and 53x 5-Star) or (1x 3-Star and 54x 5-Star).

But the available comments shown by the site for this profile make this extremely hard to believe.

Comments

1. "DO NOT LEAVE YOUR DOG HERE!! We left our dog with ***** for 5 days. When we picked him up he had REALLY, REALLY BAD DIARRHEA!! Our dog came home and defecated DIARRHEA all over our car, beds and house for ONE WEEK. We have been to the vet twice and have run up a huge bill. ... READ ALL THE REVIEWS! SEVERAL OTHERS HAVE HAD THE SAME PROBLEM! POT MIGHT BE PART OF THE PROBLEM. DON'T ROLL THE DICE WITH YOUR FAVORITE PET! AVOID LEAVING YOUR DOG HERE!!"
2. "DO NOT LEAVE YOUR DOG HERE. My 4 month old puppy came home intoxicated with marijuana. ... I am enraged right now and will have authorities go in and ensure this place is safe for pets because this is extreme."
3. "Both our dogs came home violently sick with diarrhea that has lasted days. Please do not take your dogs here. They were overcrowded with dogs and there place is not safe or sanitary for dogs."
4. "Upon arriving to ***** residence, we were greeted by lovely people in a house with a big backyard. ... We recommend anyone looking for a sitter to heed some caution before leaving their dog with these sitters and know that there is likely a better option out there if you want the best care for your dog."

Comment: Why do you think the formula that you came up with is the one they use?

Comment: @DaleM I have added my reasoning for why I think the formula I came up with is the one that they are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[§74.01](https://laws.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-34/page-11.html#h-89169) of the Competition Act says that

> A person engages in reviewable conduct who, for the purpose of
> promoting, directly or indirectly, the supply or use of a product or
> for the purpose of promoting, directly or indirectly, any business
> interest, by any means whatever,(a) makes a representation to the
> public that is false or misleading in a material respect

The legal part is fairly simple: if they make up these reviews, that violates the law. You can file a complaint [here](https://www.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/cb-bc.nsf/frm-eng/GH%C3%89T-7TDNA5), and if your argument is sufficiently compelling, the Competition Bureau may investigate, and take action.